# How can I make mortar thicker if I've put a little too much water in it?

Tags: brick, masonry

I'm working on an outdoor grill made of brick, and I've put a little too much water in the mix (80lb bag).  Can I add a little sand to make it thicker?

Comment: sand will make it weaker

Comment: But will it make it thicker?

Comment: It will not make it thicker, sand does not absorbes water

Comment: By the time you get an answer here, your mix will be set too much to do anything with it... You'll probably need to add more cement, though, not sand.

Comment: A really dry sand would make it a little thicker, but for the real fix, sand and mortar needs to be added

Comment: I appreciate the help!  My problem was I was out of mortar mix, so adding more wasn't an option.  I did put a little sand in (like 3 pints) and it did what I wanted it to.  Next batch, I won't make this mistake.